# is there a way to have three plots on each pdf I print in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with 5 different Levels and three Aspects (Sam, Dave and Sarah). I want to print 5 pdfs for each levels. each pdf has a date on each page (43 days). in each page I want to print three plots one for each person's value on y-axis and time on x-axis.

```
df<- structure(list(Levels = c("MI270E026.9D", "MI270S022.3E", "MI270S003.6D", 
"MI270W031.6D", "MI270S013.6D", "MI270E026.9E", "MI270N021.4D", 
"MI270W002.4D", "MI270E029.5D", "MI270S011.0D", "MI270S021.4D", 
"MI270N016.6D", "MI270S004.7D", "MI270W001.8D", "MI270N004.7D", 
"MI270N014.8D", "MI270E025.1D", "MI270N022.3D", "MI270N018.1D", 
"MI270S011.0D"), Date = structure(c(16534, 16583, 16571, 16534, 
16532, 16571, 16592, 16893, 16594, 16902, 16896, 16532, 16983, 
16595, 16892, 16983, 16982, 16532, 16583, 16559), class = "Date"), 
    date_time = structure(c(1428605700, 1432816200, 1431745200, 
    1428541200, 1428419700, 1431776100, 1433625300, 1459581900, 
    1433792100, 1460400000, 1459900200, 1428378900, 1467405900, 
    1433836200, 1459513500, 1467353700, 1467264300, 1428440700, 
    1432790700, 1430776200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), Aspect = c("Dave", "Sam", "Sam", "Dave", "Sam", 
    "Dave", "Dave", "Dave", "Dave", "Dave", "Sam", "Dave", "Dave", 
    "Dave", "Sarah", "Sam", "Dave", "Dave", "Sarah", "Sarah"), 
    Value = c(81.5, NA, 57, 7.3, 61, 0, 50.8, 54.8, 63.3, 86.4, 
    36, 6, 59.6, 107.5, 5, 61, 50.7, 38, 3.8, 2.8)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried the following code but it is not giving any output:

```
df <- df %>% gather(Aspect, Value, -Levels, -Date, -date_time)
df$Levels <- factor(df$Levels)
df$Date <- factor(df$Date)
library(ggplot2)
for(i in levels(df$Levels)) {
  pdf(paste0(i,'.pdf'), width = 20)
  for(j in levels(df$Date)) {
    subset.data <- df[which(df$Levels==i & df$Date==j),]
    if (nrow(subset.data)!=0) {
      p1 <-df %>% filter(Aspect == "Sam") %>%  ggplot(data=subset.data, aes(date_time, Value, group = Aspect))+
        geom_line(aes(color=Aspect)) +
        labs(title=paste('Station:',i, " Date:",j)) +
        theme_bw()
      p <-df %>% filter(Aspect == "Dave") %>%  ggplot(data=subset.data, aes(date_time, Value, group = Aspect))+
        geom_line(aes(color=Aspect)) +
        theme_bw()
      p3 <-df %>% filter(Aspect == "Sarah") %>%  ggplot(data=subset.data, aes(date_time, Value, group = Aspect))+
        geom_line(aes(color=Aspect)) +
        theme_bw()
      invisible(print(multiplot(p1, p2, p3, cols=1)))
    }
  }
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code `p` instead of `p2`

Comment: There are several packages that provide functions to combine multiple ggplot objects: `gridExtra`, `cowplot`, `patchwork`, `ggpubr`